# Can we say Copy-Right-Free instead of CopyLeft?

Tags: terminology

say a lot of people find the phrase "copy left" confusing so you may prefer to use "copyright-free" instead. is that ok? are they having exactly same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

No, they are absolutely not synonymous. Material that is copylefted *is* copyrighted — but instead of using the copyright to prevent others from freely reproducing and modifying the work, it uses the copyright to require any reproducers and modifiers to do so in a way that preserves everyone else's freedom as well.

That is: suppose I want to release a piece of software, together with its source code, and I want to allow other people to freely modify and re-distribute it. One option is to disclaim all of my rights to it, so that anyone can do absolutely anything with it; but another option is to retain my rights to it, but to publically release it under a *license*. This license stipulates that anyone can use modify and re-distribute it, *on condition that* they grant the same license to anyone that they re-distribute it to. If the work were copyright-free, then it would be meaningless to speak of "licensing" it, because I wouldn't have any right to require that anyone abide by any terms. The copyright is what allows the license to be enforced.

(Of course, "copyleft" is not specific to software; that was its original application, but it can also apply to images, to the text of wikis, and so on. Anything that can be copyrighted, can be copylefted.)

For more information, see "[What is Copyleft?](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/)" on the web-site of the Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Well, Thank you for the information. My case is piece of arts, my music actually. People are not supposed to develope a music, I want to just mention somewhere it is free music, any one can copy it and I don't except money or confirmation for freely spreading my music in youtube or in hand copies or whatever...

Comment: @user96711: You need to decide what you're O.K. with. When you say that "People are not supposed to develope a music", do you mean that you don't want people modifying your piece? Because if you declare it copyright-free, then it doesn't *matter* what you want -- you won't own the piece anymore, and you won't have the right to say that people shouldn't be modifying it.

Comment: So specieficly
I want to say as far as my name exist over the music they are free to copy or share, free to release on websites, free to use it in their art works as sound track or whatever they want, free to develop if they want of course. the only limitation is mentioning my name on there... what is the best phrase you suggest me? (of course there is thousands of other internet based musicians who work the same as me)
public domain? copy left? free to share stuff?

Comment: @user96711: You're really asking a legal question, not an English question; and I am not a lawyer, so you should the following as "random person on the Internet trying to be helpful", rather than as, y'know, legal advice. That said . . . you do *not* want to say "public domain", because that means that you are relinquishing your copyright completely; it's not compatible with "the only limitation is mentioning my name on there". It sounds like you want to license your work under [the Creative Commons "Attribution" license (CC BY)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).

Comment: Thanks buddy, you really helped. and that phrase (creative commons license) was useful. after all this question IS related to english language encyclopaedias... somebody will need these informations once upon the time and will read it here